# After adding icons of each process to dataGridView1 the last one is red x why it happens ? I checked for null but nothing is null

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In form1 I have this method that I've called through a timer, in the designer I changed the first column type to: DataGridViewImageColumn

```
private void test()
   {

    foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
                {
                    if (p.MainWindowTitle.Length > 1)
                    {
                        var icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(p.MainModule.FileName);
                        Image ima = icon.ToBitmap();
                        String status = p.Responding ? "Running" : "Not Responding";
                        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(ima,p.MainWindowTitle, status);
                    }
   }
                }
```

Now what I'm getting is this:

[image]

In first iteration I have seen all the icons but in the end I see red x . I tried to check if the variable ima is null but it is not, then checked that variable p is null or p.MainWindowTitle is null but nothing is null.
What could be the cause of this red x ?

**Second thing**(not connected to the red x issue): in the first time first iteration I have seen 9 icons(not including the red x) in the second timer iteration it's adding another icon so there are 10. Why it is not adding all the 10 icons for the first time ?

Comment: Looks like an empty row. Delete it or prevent it being added in the first place..

Comment: To me it looks like it's just the "New Row"-row, where you can enter new data. That's why it has no image data available and the other fields are empty too. Essentially you could disable that option of the DataGridView with `myGrid.AllowUserToAddRows = false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with datagridview property `AllowUserToAddRows = false`
This way it wont show the last empty row.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove it.

```
var row = dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridview.Rows.Count-1];
dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
```

Regarding the 2nd issue. Is that 10th process running at the first time as well? What process is that?